# how to separate/filter an output string and write the separated data into different text boxes?

Tags: c#, .net, string, nslookup

So i have a button and two text boxes.
I want to click a button, it will execute nslookup then i want to :

```
-write the resolved hostname into one text box
-write the resolved ip adress into next text box
```

I have this so far

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "nslookup.exe";
                psi.Arguments = "google.com";

                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
                p.StartInfo = psi;
                p.Start();

                p.WaitForExit();

                System.IO.StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput;

                textbox1.Text = output.ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

So now it does the resolution and writes everything into one string. 
How can i filter the output string and write specific parts of the string into separate boxes ?

Example output string will be : ( it is a single line string but i wrote it here in a table for easy understanding )

```
Server:  EXAMPLE //this i dont need
Address:  EXAMPLE //this i dont need

Name:    google.com //i need this to be written to TextBox1
Address: 172.217.21.206 //i need this to be written to TextBox2
```

So that in the end :

```
Textbox.Text = "google.com"
Textbox2.Text = "172.217.21.206"
```

Later i want to ping the ip in textbox2 and make the text box change color if its reachable, and a button to rdp connect to that ip if its reachable, so i need it to not have any spaces and just be a string

I was thinking to write each word that is separated by a space into an array and then read the array and write things that match into the boxes with something like this  :

```
string[] words = outputstring.Split(' ');

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"<{word}>");
        }
```

But before i continue with it i wanted to ask if there is an easier and faster way to do it and im going in the wrong direction alltogether ? maybe there is a way to just return specific parameters out of the nslookup command ?

Comment: `nslookup` will return several ip addresses, which one you want?

Comment: Bear in mind that, as it says in the [nslookup] wiki, general support for nslookup is off topic here.

Comment: Why not use Dns.GetHostByName ("google.com"); from System.Net and than use the result to fill the Text Boxes?

Comment: Yeah dns.gethostbyname is the best and fastest way, i looked everywhere on the internet for something like it but couldnt find it, i am a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dns.GetHostEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of manually calling external process:

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("example.com");
textbox1.Text = hostInfo.HostName;
textbox2.Text = hostInfo.AddressList[yourIndex].ToString();
```

Comment: so what do i put in "yourIndex" ? if i put 1 or 2 it throws an index out of range exception

Comment: @JohnLinaer It depends what you want to get, for example for `google.com` it returns about `10` addresses, what you want to show? What is your task?

Comment: Also you maybe will need to put this in `try/catch` if it will be user input, cause it will throw `SocketException` if host address will not be found.

Comment: well i have servers that are in my network, so a server host name would be example.domain.com, so then i wanna do an nslookup on "example" and it would return example.domain.com and that should be written into the text box. when i do nslookup using cmd it shows 2 names, first the domain one which usually is the first, and then the second which is  the hostname that i am looking for, so basically i want it to return the hostname of the server + domain
there is no user input, i just wanna make a server status checker, to see if the server is online + show the info like hostname and ip adress

Comment: @JohnLinaer What happened to ip address in question?

Comment: oh wait we are talking about the second box, sorry my bad
well i would say then it should return the first ip address resolved, since most of my servers have only one. Well then obviously the index is 0. it is working now sorry i had a brain fart and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can help you here. Here's how you could retrieve the name, for the address it would be similar:

```
Regex.Match(text, @"Name: *(?<name>[^ ]+)").Groups["name"].Value
```

Comment: How does this cope with multiple lines with "Name: " ?